# Is it a way to keep contentOffset after reloading tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I need to reload tableview, but in somehow I want to keep the scroll position. Any way to do it? Maybe store content offset and in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` I should reset it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TableView does not reset scroll position. It maintains content offset even after reloadData function is called. So no need to do anything, if you want to keep pixel position.

If you are changing row height at the time of reloading data or changing datasource then you can use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your current offset before reloading the table use this method to save your current offset

```
self.tableView.contentOffset.y
```

Or you can Reload like this it will Reload your table from your current Offset
Try this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
     self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, currentOffset);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

just call `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` before you use reloadData (with animation:NO)

Also, be carefull in case you have less cells in the updated tableview to prevent crashes.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

After reloading the table view you need to call the TableView's method `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated`:

Just provide the index path, scroll position which could be one of the following

```
UITableViewScrollPositionNone,
UITableViewScrollPositionTop,    
UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle,   
UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
```

and YES/ NO in animated parameter.